# Unable to add a reference to System.Data.XML

Tags: .net, linq

I pulled down a working website from a live to local environment. Everything worked fine except a reference I had to the System.Data.XML namespace, which gave me the standard error about it not being found.

I first confirmed that my application pool in IIS for this site was set to 4.0.

Next I checked the target framework of the site in Visual Studio, which is set to 3.5.

I then looked through the web.config and did find System.Data.Linq (along with System.Core) listed.

I tried adding the reference via Visual Studio. This modified my web.config to add a duplicate  section with this line

```
<add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
```

I next tried targeting 4.0 to see if that changed anything. The namespace now is pulled up correctly, but any calls to LINQ functions fail.

Assemblies section of web.config is as follows

```
  <compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="true">
    <assemblies>
      <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    </assemblies>
  </compilation>
```

Comment: Are you sure there *is* a `System.Data.XML`? I just use `System.XML` and it works fine (and so does `System.XML.Schemas`).

Comment: I double checked -- it's available from the list of references, and also works fine on the live site